# A Haskell function that receives a List with different types and returns only an Integer List

Tags: haskell, types

I have a function like this:

```
[(String, [Int], Int)]
```

I desire a function that just returns a list of [Int].

Input example:

```
[("R1",[6,10,14],6),("R2",[8,10,14],8),("R3",[11,15,24],11)]
```

Output example (the behavior that I want of the output):

```
[6,8,10,11,14,15,24]
```

I've been thinking to create a function of input, like this:

```
function :: [(String, [Int], Int)]
function = [("R1",[6,10,14],6),("R2",[8,10,14],8),("R3",[11,15,24],11)]
```

And another to convert to what I desire, like this :

```
convert :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
convert [] = []
...
```

How can I develop the function `convert`?

Comment: Hint: use a `map`ping.

Comment: Start by writing a pair of helper functions with types `[(String, [Int], Int)] -> ([[Int]], [Int])` and `([[Int]], [Int]) -> [Int])`. (And the first one might benefit from *another* helper with type `(String, [Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)`. Don't be afraid to define lots and lots of small functions.)

Comment: What does "I have a function like this: `'[(String, [Int], Int)]'`" mean?

Comment: The thing you are calling `function` *isn't* a function; it's just list of tuples.

Comment: https://mathinsight.org/definition/function

Comment: Could you elaborate how the `Int` extraction should work? It's not immediately clear from the example you've given, at first I thought that you just want to take the `[Int]` components of each tuple, maybe concatenate them, but it doesn't appear to agree with the output you've posted.

Comment: @Michail It looks like it's supposed to be sorted after concatenation.

Comment: @amalloy And then deduplicated; also, the third element of the tuple may or may not be involved somehow. Too much guesswork, really.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I like to do is lay out all the type signatures I think I'll need:

```
-- Something to use with fmap to get rid of the Strings
f :: (String, [Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)

-- Something to cons the list with the Int
g :: ([Int], Int) -> [Int]

-- Our final goal:
convert :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
```

Now I like to think about how I can compose these together to get my final result:

```
fmap g . fmap f :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [[Int]]
```

And thanks to the [functor laws](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Functor) you can actually rewrite that as:

```
fmap (g . f) :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [[Int]]
```

Thats pretty close, but we have two nested lists instead of one. Luckily list is a [monoid](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/Prelude.html#t:Monoid) which means that we can use `mconcat :: [a] -> a` to fold it. Thats a little confusing because `mconcat` operates on a list of monoidal `a` values. The more concrete signature for `mconcat` in our case would be:

```
mconcat :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

Where the `monoid` we are `mappending` is the inner list.

Regardless, what that allows us to do is write this:

```
mconcat . fmap (g . f) :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
```

Which is exactly the function we are trying to implement:

```
convert :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
convert = mconcat . fmap g . fmap f
    where f = undefined
          g = undefined
```

Now we just need to implement `f` and `g`:

```
f :: (String, [Int], Int) -> ([Int], Int)
f (_, xs, x) = (xs, x)

g :: ([Int], Int) -> [Int] 
g (xs, x) = x:xs

g' :: ([Int], Int) -> [Int] 
g' (xs, x) = xs ++ [x]
```

Depending what position you want `x` to go in you can use `g` or `g'`.

Then your final implementation would be something like ([sort](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.18/base-4.12.0.0/Data-List.html#v:sort) added to the composition to match your example result):

```
convert :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
convert = sort . mconcat . fmap g . fmap f
    where f (_, xs, x) = (xs, x)
          g (xs, x) = x:xs
```

Looking back at your question, it looks like the 3rd element of the triple is always a member of the second element? If thats the case, this function becomes even simpler:

```
convert :: [(String, [Int], Int)] -> [Int]
convert = sort . mconcat . fmap f
    where f (_, xs, ) = xs
```

If you are worried about performance due to the final sort step, you could combine it with the concatenation by using `foldr` to rather then `mconcat` and do the sorting in the `a -> b -> b`.